# [Node.js, MongoDB/Mongoose]: Generating a unique list of tags using indexOf is very slow

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a two models, a video model and a global statistic model. The video model stores an array of strings for tags. The global statistics model stores an array of `tagCountSchema` that contains `tag` and `count`.

I am writing a function that deletes and rebuilds the global statistic documents using data from the video documents. This includes rebuilding the list of unique tags and their counts in the global statistics document.

```
const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tags: [{ type: String }],
});

const tagCountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tag: { type: String, required: true },
    count: { type: Number, default: 1 },
}, { _id: false });

const statisticSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    is: { type: String, default: 'global' },
    tags: [tagCountSchema],
});

const Statistic = mongoose.model('Statistic', statisticSchema );
const Video = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema );
```

```
// Rebuild the statistics document
let statistics = await Statistic.findOne({ is: 'global' });
let videos = await Video.find({});

let map = statistics.tags.map(e => e.tag);

for (let video of videos) {    
    for (let tag of video.tags) {
        const index = map.indexOf(tag);
        if (index === -1) {
            statistics.tags.push({ tag: tag, count: 1 });
            map.push(tag);
        } else {
            statistics.tags[index].count++;
        }
    }
}

await statistics.save();
```

However, the use of `indexOf()` in the function above makes rebuilding the statistics take a **very** long time. Since videos have a lot of unique tags, the array of unique tags on the global statistics document becomes really long and since `indexOf()` needs to be called for each tag of each video the function takes a long time to complete.

I tested a version of this function that stored tags as an Object in the database and used `Object.keys` to update tags in the statistics document. This was an order of magnitude faster but I have come to realize that storing tag names directly as an object in the database would cause issues if the tag name was illegal to use as a database key.

It is also technically possible I could stringify the tags object to store it, but that is not convent for how this function is used in other places of my code. As the function loops through videos it is also updating similar statistics for other documents (such as uploader) which I have left out of the code for simplicities sake. This would mean it would need to stringify and destringify the object for every video.

What can I improve the speed of this function?

Comment: Can you show what `map` looks like right after: `let map = statistics.tags.map(e => e.name);`?

Comment: @codemonkey sorry, that `name` should have been `tag`, updated the question. `map` is an array of tag names built from the array of `tagCountSchema` in order to get the index of the tag.

Comment: How big an array are we talking? How many elements in it? I am asking to explore the possibility of preprocessing it before that loop to make it much faster to look up.

Comment: The number of unique tags is currently almost 11,000 but it has the potential to grow much larger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your aproach is not quite good.
It would be simplier if you update your statitics as you register your videos.

This way you will avoid the building index problem. Or you can use a queue to update your data.

This is way i would do

Comment: That is how my code already works 99% of the time. The reason I am doing something different here and rebuilding the statistics is that this function is part of an update utility for my script in which documents need to be rebuilt to match the new format, add new statistics, etc. This function only runs once (to apply the update) and never again, however, it is problematic because in its current state it can potentially take hours to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem in my line of work and had to get a little creative to avoid that `indexOf` (in my case `find`) function, because, as you already know, it's a hugely expensive operation.

On the other hand, as you may know, looking up keys of an object is pretty much instant. So I would rewrite the code that builds the statistics document like so:

```
const map = {};
statistics.tags.map((e, i) => {
    map[e.tag] = i
});

for (let video of videos) {
    for (let tag of video.tags) {
        if (tag in map) {
            statistics.tags[map[tag]].count++;
        } else {
            statistics.tags.push({ tag, count: 1 });
            map[tag] = Object.keys(map).length;
        }
    }
}
```

This will significantly speed up your nested loop.